# How to generate a Excel From JSON file with colors using python

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

I have two json files like this having different skill score

`Data 1`

```
  {
     "agent_pk": 15004,
     "agent_name": "ABC",
     "skill_details": [
       {
         "skill_name": "rules.close.urgency.score",
         "skill_score": 0.0
       },
       {
         "skill_name": "rules.open.develop_rpc.score",
         "skill_score": 0.7
       }
     ]
  },
  {
    "agent_pk": 15005,
    "agent_name": "BCD",
    "skill_details": [
      {
        "skill_name": "rules.close.urgency.score",
        "skill_score": 0.2
      },
      {
        "skill_name": "rules.open.develop_rpc.score",
        "skill_score": 0.3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

`Data 2`

```
  {
    "agent_pk": 15004,
    "agent_name": "ABC",
    "skill_details": [
      {
        "skill_name": "rules.close.urgency.score",
        "skill_score": 0.6
      },
      {
        "skill_name": "rules.open.develop_rpc.score",
        "skill_score": 2.0
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "agent_pk": 15005,
    "agent_name": "BCD",
    "skill_details": [
      {
        "skill_name": "rules.close.urgency.score",
        "skill_score": 0.2
      },
      {
        "skill_name": "rules.open.develop_rpc.score",
        "skill_score": 0.3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I make a new excel sheet like this using above data in python

| ABC | Score 1 | Score 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| rules.close.urgency.score | 0.0 | 0.6 |
| rules.open.develop_rpc.skill_score | 0.7 | 2.0 |
| **BCD** | **Score 1** | **Score 2** |
| rules.close.urgency.score | 0.2 | 0.3 |
| rules.open.develop_rpc.skill_score | 0.2 | 0.3 |

Answer (score 1):

You can try this :

```
with open("data1.json", "r") as f1, \
     open("data2.json", "r") as f2:
    df1 = pd.json_normalize(json.load(f1), "skill_details")
    df2 = pd.json_normalize(json.load(f2), "skill_details")

out = (df1.set_axis(["ABC", "Data 1"], axis=1)
            .join(df2.iloc[:, -1].rename("Data 2")))

def color(ser):
    conds = [
        (ser.eq(0)),
        (ser.ge(0.1)) & (ser.le(1.9)),
        (ser.eq(2.0))
    ]
    vals = [
        "background-color: yellow",
        "background-color: red",
        "background-color: green"
    ]
    return np.select(conds, vals, default="")

s = out.style.apply(color, subset=["Data 1", "Data 2"]).format(precision=1)

#s.to_excel("output.xlsx", index=False) #uncomment this line to make a spreadsheet
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: i have updated the question can you please help me with that